# Expected value of first success in Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, expected-value

I have a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli experiments each succeeding with probability $p$.
In general, the number of successes $X$ follows the well-known binomial distribution:

$$P(X = k) = \begin{pmatrix} n\\ k \end{pmatrix} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

However, I'm interested in the expected value of the number of experiments until the *first* success, assuming a maximum number of $n$ trials (if the experiment never succeeds, there will have been $n$ experiments attempted).

My reasoning is the following: if $n = 4$, the expected value will be (?):

$$ 1\cdot p + 2\cdot(1-p)p + 3\cdot(1-p)^2p + 4\cdot(1-p)^3p + 5(1-p)^5$$

Generalizing:

$$E = \sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot p(1-p)^{i-1}$$

However, the sum of these weights is not one, as it should be:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n p(1-p)^{i-1} \neq 1$$

Clearly I'm off somewhere. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why exactly it should be $1$? Keep in mind that you are calculating expected value of the random variable, not probability distribution.

Comment: The expected value shouldn't be one, but the sum of the coefficients should

Comment: If I understand well then to be found is the expected value of a random variable $Z$. It will take a value in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ if a success appears in the first $n$ trials. Could you tell us what value $Z$ will take if that does not happen?

Comment: That is correct. If none of the $n$ trials is successful, $Z$ will be $n$.

Comment: Your probability distribution is based on the assumption that it will succeed ultimately. If you add in the probability that it doesn't succeed at all, your weights will add up to $1$.

Comment: Of course... derp. Thank you. I posted and answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting $q:=1-p$ for $n=4$ we find:

$$p\cdot1+qp\cdot2+q^2p\cdot3+(1-p-qp-q^2p)\cdot4$$

Answer (score 0):

Expected value:

$$E = n\cdot(1 - \sum_{i=1}^N p(1-p)^{i-1}) + \sum_{i=1}^N i\cdot p(1-p)^{i-1}$$

Comment: As it hasn't been mentioned yet in comments, in case you don't know, your scenario is similar to a Geometric distribution.

Comment: I think $N$ should be changed into $n-1$